# How to erase CustomMarker from google maps v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, customization, markerclusterer

I have problem with the Custom Markers in google maps. I'll try to explain as best I can.

I have some markers, and I did one Asyntask, that clusterize it if is necessary, returning a `LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusters` where I have the clusters. Each position represents a cluster (it's possible to have a cluster with 1 marker)

When I got this list, I add the Clusters to the map:

here is the activity where i Call to Clusterizer.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        CameraUpdate camUpd1 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(41.40520680710329,2.191342011603923),MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL);       
        map.animateCamera(camUpd1);

        loadMarkers();  

        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                if(position.zoom != oldZoom) {
                    try {

                        clusters = null;                        
                        map.clear();
                        Clusterizer.setContext(getApplicationContext());
                        clusters = Clusterizer.clusterMarkers(map, markers, INTERVAL);

                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }               
                oldZoom = position.zoom;
            }
        }); 

    }


    private void loadMarkers() {

        markers.add(new Marker(41.40520680710229,2.191342011603823,"Glorias1","Centro Comercial",true).getMarker());
        markers.add(new Marker(41.40520680710229+0.0005,2.191342011603823-0.0005,"Glorias11","Centro Comercial",true).getMarker());
        markers.add(new Marker(41.40520680710229+0.0005,2.191342011603823+0.0005,"Glorias111","Centro Comercial",true).getMarker());
        markers.add(new Marker(41.40520680710229-0.0005,2.191342011603823+0.0005,"Glorias1111","Centro Comercial",true).getMarker());
        markers.add(new Marker(41.40520680710229-0.0005,2.191342011603823-0.0005,"Glorias1111","Centro Comercial",true).getMarker());
    }
```

And, in the Asyntask after calculate the clusters (it does ok) the postExecute method, does this:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(
                LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusters) {

            map.clear();
            for(Point point: clusters.keySet()) {
                ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markersForPoint = clusters.get(point);
                MarkerOptions mainMaker= markersForPoint.get(0);
                //If the point (taken from cluster, has more than 1 markerOption, means that has been clusterized, so It have to be printed with the //modified canvas that contains the number of markers clusterized)
                if(markersForPoint.size() > 1) {  
                    mainMaker.title(Integer.toString(markersForPoint.size()));  

                    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 80, conf);
                    Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp);
                    Paint color = new Paint();
                    color.setTextSize(35);
                    color.setColor(Color.BLACK
                    canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                            R.drawable.pin), 0,0, color);                   
                    canvas1.drawText("",10,40,color);
                    canvas1.drawText(Integer.toString(markersForPoint.size()), 10, 40, color);

                    mainMaker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp));
                    mainMaker.anchor(0.5f, 1);
                }
                map.addMarker(mainMaker);
            }
        }
```

And here's the problem...

If it's clustered there's no problem, it shows ok, but when I made zoom in the `cluster list` it's ok, but the marker isn't

Thats hoow looks the cluster when is "clustered" and when is suposed to not be clustered

How can I fix it? I clean the map before add markers...

Thanks for all!

**Clustered:**

[image]

**Not Clustered**
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you ask for.

Comment: @MaciejGórski I try to explain in other way.. ^^. When I do Zoom in or Zoom out on the map, if the markers are to close (mesured in pixel on the screen) I cluster the one which are to close (for example 70 px). When the markers are clustered , i dont use the default marker of GMap, I use a custommarker, "drawed" with the numbers of markers that represents. But when I do Zoom in (the cluster disappear and now Is possible to see the 5 markers (for example), the marker that represented the cluster, is still custom, when is supposed to be the default marker.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
        color.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
```

You may have to tweak the origin of your paint to be centered in the marker.

Answer (score 0):

> I clean the map before add markers...

I can't see the clearing code and it seems like you don't call `Marker.remove()` on old ones. Clearly you have a problem with algorithm and it will be not possible to answer if you don't provide full code.

You may instead try one of the open-source clustering algorithms for Google Maps Android API v2: [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) or [Clusterkraf](https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf). The latter seems to be closer to what you want to achieve - it is distance based.

Comment: I have added more coded to be more clear. I use `map.clear()` to clean the map from markers. And in the postExecute() of the AsynTask, is where I "draw" the custom marker if the marker is clusterized